# Feather icon or Font-awesome icon not showing when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using feather icon and font-awesome. I am generating a dropdown element using ajax and innerHTML. My problem is I can generate the dropdown but the icon is not showing. Does innerHTML function interfere with the initialization of the icon? if so, what alternatives can I use?

Here is my sample code:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 btn-grp-hidden" id="btn-grp"></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'generate-loan-application-btn-grp.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'TEXT',
    data: {clientid : clientid, name : name, status : status, applno : applno, effectiveyield : effectiveyield, term : term, repaymentamt : repaymentamt, amtfinanced : amtfinanced, frequency : frequency, firstname : firstname, lastname : lastname, middlename : middlename},
    success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("btn-grp").innerHTML = response;
    }
});
```

PHP code:

```
$response = '<div class="btn-group dropdown dropdown-triangle">
<button class="btn btn-brand btn-long dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="text">Right-aligned menu</span>
    <span class="icon"><span data-feather="chevron-down" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right nav">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span data-feather="plus-circle" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span><span>Action</span><span class="rui-nav-circle"></span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span data-feather="x-circle" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span><span>Another action</span><span class="rui-nav-circle"></span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span data-feather="check-circle" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span><span>Something else here</span><span class="rui-nav-circle"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>';

echo $response;
```

Comment: Please hit f12 and advise if there are any console errors?

Comment: @EGC there were no console errors found

Answer (score 5):

Are you able to find your feather-icon tags inside the html?

If yes then put your `feather.replace()` inside

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
feather.replace() 
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let response = `<div class="btn-group dropdown dropdown-triangle">
<button class="btn btn-brand btn-long dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="text">Right-aligned menu</span>
    <span class="icon"><span data-feather="chevron-down" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right nav">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span data-feather="plus-circle" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span><span>Action</span><span class="rui-nav-circle"></span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span data-feather="x-circle" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span><span>Another action</span><span class="rui-nav-circle"></span></a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span data-feather="check-circle" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5"></span><span>Something else here</span><span class="rui-nav-circle"></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>`;
  console.log(response);
  document.getElementById("btn-grp").innerHTML = response;
  feather.replace()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 btn-grp-hidden" id="btn-grp"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with finding feather-icon tag?

Comment: Using browser console you can check if there is all the present that you are fetching through ajax.

Comment: feather.replace()  code is working fine in ajax files. Thank you @Akbar Ali.